# Timing functions on cortex-m1 gives weird results

Tags: c, arm, timing, cortex-m

I'm having problems timing functions on cortex-M1. I'm using an Arty A7 and I'm using systick to count the clock duration of a function. The problem is that the clocks I'm getting don't make sense, while prototyping the function on my PC I measured its clock duration with clock() from time.h - it took about 5000 clocks. Next I tried to measure it on cortex-M1 and used systick to count the clocks - now the results showed millions of clocks, which I think doesn't make sense.

Here is how I measure using systick

```
#define STCTRL      (*( ( uint32_t *) 0xE000E010 ))
#define STRELOAD    (*( ( uint32_t *) 0xE000E014 ))
#define STCURR      (*( ( uint32_t *) 0xE000E018 ))

int main(void)
{
    SystemInit();
    STRELOAD = 16000000;
    uint32_t start, stop;

    STCTRL = (1<<0) | (1<<2);
    wait(1000);
    start = STCURR;
    function();
    stop = STCURR;
    STCTRL = (0<<0);
    printf("%d", (int)(start-stop));
}
```

I'm not sure how relevant this information is, but when prototyping i compiled with gcc-9 and used -O3 -Otime, when compiling for cortex-M1 I use armcc v5.06 - update 7 with flags: --c99 --gnu -c --cpu Cortex-M1 -D__EVAL --li -g -O3 -Otime

My question is how and why are the 2 measurements so different? Am I doing something wrong when measuring clock cycles (either with clock() or systick)?

Comment: I don't know anything about this processor, but there's no reason the way the time library implements `clock()` should be the same as direct readings of a system timer.  What is the time.h value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC ?

Comment: The difference in tick counts is not relevant. You have scale them to real-time values. For `clock()` it's CLOCKS_PER_SEC, but for your Cortex-M1 board, it really depends on how you've got it configured.  See https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0413/d/system-control/system-control-register-descriptions/systick-control-and-status-register

Comment: just leave/use the reload at 0x00FFFFFF, then simply subtract start from finish or finish from start depending on if it is a down or up count.  and remember to and the subtraction with 0x00FFFFFF so that it rolls around properly.  delta = (x - y)&0x00FFFFFF.

Comment: how do you prototype this on your pc and have any kind of relevant time?  are you saying you run it in a sim of the arty board?  no reason to expect any two different processors to have remotely the same time for the same code.  likewise if you add or remove any lines of code the execution time on the arty may change (expected).

Comment: I prefer to have the code under test in asm and have the read the clock stuff as part of the test, because doing it in C like this can add/remove some clocks from one build to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your register definitions are wrong because they are missing out `volatile`:

```
#define SysTick_TCTRL      (*((volatile uint32_t*)0xE000E010))
etc.
```

Next, you need to set `SysTick_LOAD` to `(period - 1)`, not `period`. In your example the period is 16000001.

After that, systick counts down and wraps at 24 bits or the limit that you set, so you need to undo this with modulo or just if-then-subtract.  Modulo is tidier but the divide pulls in libraries on ARMv6M.

```
if (start > stop)
{
  duration = (start - stop);
}
else
{
  duration = (period - (stop - start));
}
```

Comment: First, I agree, I need to make the register definitions volatile. Second, the actual period number isn't really relevant, that 16000000 I put there is just some big number that I know won't run out before my function execution is done.

Comment: It is relevant because the initial value of the timer is undefined.  It could wrap immediately.

Comment: It's undefined in my example? Why do I care if my period is 16000000 or 16000001? Why would it wrap, shouldn't the max value be 2^24 - 1?

Comment: Suppose the counter starts with the value 3 (it can be anything, that is what undefined means).  If your function takes 4 or more cycles, then it will wrap and you get a very large number, as you have discovered.

Comment: When it wraps it gets the value from the reload register, it does not start with the value from the reload register.

Comment: Hmm, I used this link as reference, in it i found that setting the enable bit in the control and status register loads the counter with reload value and begins counting down.
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0413/d/system-control/system-control-register-descriptions/systick-control-and-status-register

Comment: My apologies, it does start with a the reload value, but that is before you call wait(1000).  Even if you took that out, you wouldn't normally want to have to restart the SysTick every occasion you time something.  Normally you would just let it run freely, take two readings and unwap the difference using the code in the answer above.